# Restrict editing Word Style or Context Menu popup

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-addins

Is it possible to lock Word Styles and block the user from editing them or can the context menu be disabled?

I have tried:

```
foreach (W.Style st in doc.Styles)
{ 
 if (st.NameLocal == "Beispiel" || st.NameLocal == "Standard")
    st.Locked = true;            
}            
object noReset = false;            
object password = "";            
object useIrm = false;            
object enforceStyleLock = false;            
doc.Protect(W.WdProtectionType.wdNoProtection,              
  ref noReset, ref password, ref useIrm, ref enforceStyleLock);
```

But this option loks the whole TabHome but I only want to lock the styles in this Tab. Users should only be able the add them by clicking. Every other function e.g. "Modify Styles" should be disabled.

I have searched and tried different controls but almost non of the style controls gets fired.

Comment: This corresponds to Restrict Editing/Formatting restrictions in the Developer tab - you might want to experiment with that in the UI to get a better feel for it. It's *purpose* is to allow users to only apply "approved" formatting to a document. It's purpose is not to prevent the editing of styles, only. It certainly does *not* disable the entire Home tab, just the formatting commands that are locked out. Where do you find an option that lets the user actually modify any style that has been locked?

Comment: You might be able to disable the context menu. Beware: this requires modifications in the registry. Take a look at the answer here: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/Lync/en-US/e9702419-94eb-41a2-b479-3290a4f87842/word-2010-remove-rightclick-context-menu?forum=word  You will need the correct ID of that context menu, which you might find in this list (for Office 2016): https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50745

Comment: @LocEngineer I have tried various Policy IDs from the wordcontrols.xlsx but non of the functionalities got disabled.

Comment: @CindyMeister Thanks for response. I did not quite understand what you mean. Could give more hints/explanations. How to handle the Styles in Developer tab in Word?

Comment: In the Developer tab of the Ribbon, click the button "Restrict Editing". The first option in that task pane is "Formatting restrictions". Click the link there and read the information in the dialog box.